# Flutter: How to insert Icon/Action based on X Y percent position of image

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to insert a Icon/Action based on X Y percent position of image as follows:

[image]

This is Json file:

```
[
  {
    "seasonName": "Spring",
    "isDaySelected": true,
    "listButton": "Sky",
    "pointXPercent": 66.0,
    "pointYPercent": 12.0,
    "pointName": "Bird",
    "pointDialog": "this is a bird"
  },
  {
    "seasonName": "Spring",
    "isDaySelected": true,
    "listButton": "Sky",
    "pointXPercent": 53.6,
    "pointYPercent": 27.4,
    "pointName": "Cloud",
    "pointDialog": "this is a cloud"
  },
  {
    "seasonName": "Spring",
    "isDaySelected": true,
    "listButton": "Land",
    "pointXPercent": 38.5,
    "pointYPercent": 78.3,
    "pointName": "Flower",
    "pointDialog": "this is a flower"
  },
  {
    "seasonName": "Spring",
    "isDaySelected": false,
    "listButton": "Land",
    "pointXPercent": 55.3,
    "pointYPercent": 79.8,
    "pointName": "Meadow",
    "pointDialog": "this is a meadow"
  },
  {
    "seasonName": "Summer",
    "isDaySelected": true,
    "listButton": "Sky",
    "pointXPercent": 38.9,
    "pointYPercent": 23.5,
    "pointName": "Sun",
    "pointDialog": "this is the sun"
  }
]
```

I want that when click on the `TogglesButton` "Sky" => get data from Json:

1. Get values **seasonName** = "Spring" (because `TabBar` is being
   selected as "Spring")
2. Get values that satisfy (1) and have **isDaySelected** = "true" (because the `TogglesButton` **isDaySelected** is being selected as true)
3. Get values that satisfy (1) and (2) and **listButton** = "Sky"
4. Show the **pointName** values that satisfy (1) (2) (3) on image based on X Y percent. Ex:

- pointName: "Bird" => **pointXPercent** = 66.0, **pointYPercent** = 12.0
- pointName: "Cloud" => **pointXPercent** = 53.6, **pointYPercent** = 27.4

So pls help me, this is main file:

```
import 'package:ask/model/season_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/season_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SeasonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SeasonPage() : super();
  @override
  _SeasonPageState createState() => _SeasonPageState();
}

class _SeasonPageState extends State<SeasonPage> {
  List<Season> _season = [];
  List<bool> isDaySelected = [true, false];
  List<bool> listButton = [false, false, false];

  final String springDay = 'https://i.imgur.com/MUuCuYI.png';
  final String springNight = 'https://i.imgur.com/QxbAg8Y.png';
  final String summerDay = 'https://i.imgur.com/9Qi6oLm.png';
  final String summerNight = 'https://i.imgur.com/jrFGHvn.png';
  final String autumnDay = 'https://i.imgur.com/yo0RWi6.png';
  final String autumnNight = 'https://i.imgur.com/iPW4r2g.png';
  final String winterDay = 'https://i.imgur.com/CnFDmEJ.png';
  final String winterNight = 'https://i.imgur.com/lFNdvDe.png';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SeasonServices.getSeason().then((seasons) {
      setState(() {
        _season = seasons;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: DefaultTabController(
            length: 4,
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Season'),
                  bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
                    Tab(child: Text('Spring')),
                    Tab(child: Text('Summer')),
                    Tab(child: Text('Autumn')),
                    Tab(child: Text('Winter')),
                  ]),
                ),
                body: Column(children: [
                  Center(
                      child: ToggleButtons(
                          children: [Text('Day'), Text('Night')],
                          onPressed: (int index) {
                            setState(() {
                              for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < isDaySelected.length; buttonIndex++) {
                                if (buttonIndex == index) {
                                  isDaySelected[buttonIndex] = true;
                                } else {
                                  isDaySelected[buttonIndex] = false;
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          isSelected: isDaySelected)),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Center(
                      child: ToggleButtons(
                          children: [Text('Sky'), Text('Mountain'), Text('Land')],
                          onPressed: (int index) {
                            setState(() {
                              for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < listButton.length; buttonIndex++) {
                                if (buttonIndex == index) {
                                  listButton[buttonIndex] = !listButton[buttonIndex];
                                } else {
                                  listButton[buttonIndex] = false;
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          isSelected: listButton)),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(children: [
                      isDaySelected[0] ? Image.network(springDay) : Image.network(springNight),
                      isDaySelected[0] ? Image.network(summerDay) : Image.network(summerNight),
                      isDaySelected[0] ? Image.network(autumnDay) : Image.network(autumnNight),
                      isDaySelected[0] ? Image.network(winterDay) : Image.network(winterNight),
                    ]),
                  )
                ]))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achive result

Use Stack and wrap it in IntrinsicHeight to set it height as you image height

```
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/MUuCuYI.png'),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(.66 * 2 - 1, .12 * 2 - 1),
                  child: Text('bird'),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(.536 * 2 - 1, .274 * 2 - 1),
                  child: Text('cloud'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

This will be sized to Stack children max height and until network image loaded(finally you know size) it will be tall as max of bird or cloud heigh

Note that `IntrinsicHeight` is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible.

For more complex cases you can use LayoutBuilder

```
        body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) {
                return Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                      top: .12 * constraints.biggest.height,
                      left: .66 * constraints.biggest.width,
                      child: Text('bird'),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: .274 * constraints.biggest.height,
                      left: .536 * constraints.biggest.width,
                      child: Text('cloud'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

PS Here we laying out by left&top of our bird&cloud
If you need to layout by center of birs&cloud - you have to know their sizes and do a little bit more math

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `Stack`, this is the [result](https://i.imgur.com/tdX3Yi2.jpg) is there a way for it to get the `height` and `width` of the image instead of `Expand`?

Comment: Wow!!!, It really works, thank you so much, only one thing that how to call it from JSON with `pointXPercent` and `pointyPercent` ,I am a newbie to the code, can you help me, or should I create another post?

Comment: If just started I would recommend - please read docs and get introduced to [json parsing](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) and if question will arise ask it =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Align to choose the position in a stack like this:

```
Stack(children: [
    child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment(-.40, -.90),
        child: MyPictureWidget()
    ),
]);
```

Nicer because you don't need to get the constraints. :)  `Alignment(0, 0)` would be at the center

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but how to align in the [image](https://i.imgur.com/OKWRcDv.jpg) instead of the `Expand`?