# Flutter: How to filter data from JSON based on TabBar and ToggleButtons?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "continentName": "NA",
    "isDayTime": true,
    "seasonName": "Spring",
    "cityName": "United States",
    "xAlign": 45.4,
    "yAlign": 69,
    "cityTemperature": 27
  },
  {
    "continentName": "NA",
    "isDayTime": true,
    "seasonName": "Spring",
    "cityName": "Canada",
    "xAlign": 35.7,
    "yAlign": 53,
    "cityTemperature": 16
  },
  {
    "continentName": "NA",
    "isDayTime": true,
    "seasonName": "Summer",
    "cityName": "Mexico",
    "xAlign": 87.8,
    "yAlign": 41.8,
    "cityTemperature": 28
  },
  {
    "continentName": "NA",
    "isDayTime": false,
    "seasonName": "Summer",
    "cityName": "Cuba",
    "xAlign": 55.3,
    "yAlign": 88.8,
    "cityTemperature": 27
  },
  {
    "continentName": "EU",
    "isDayTime": true,
    "seasonName": "Winter",
    "cityName": "Germany",
    "xAlign": 33.8,
    "yAlign": 38.8,
    "cityTemperature": 3
  }
]
```

I want to display the filtered data as follows:

[image]

1. The 1st filter is `TabBar` ("continentName")
2. The 2nd filter is `ToggleButtons` ("isDayTime") => *requiring at least one selection*
3. The 3rd filter is `ToggleButtons` ("listSeason") => *mutually exclusive selection, but allows for none of the buttons to be selected.*

When start the page, by default, `Tabbar` is selected as "NA", the first `toggleButtons` ("isDayTime") is selected as "Day" => **I want that if click on "Spring" => it will display the satisfying data, specifically here will be "United States" and "Canada"**

So please help me, this is main file:

```
import 'package:ask/model/temperature_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/temperature_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CityTemperature extends StatefulWidget {
  CityTemperature() : super();
  @override
  _CityTemperatureState createState() => _CityTemperatureState();
}

class _CityTemperatureState extends State<CityTemperature> {
  List<Temperature> _temperature = [];
  List<bool> isDayTime = [true, false];
  List<bool> listSeason = [false, false, false, false];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    TemperatureServices.getTemperature().then((temperature) {
      setState(() {
        _temperature = temperature;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: DefaultTabController(
            length: 4,
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Temperature'),
                  bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
                    Tab(child: Text('NA')),
                    Tab(child: Text('EU')),
                    Tab(child: Text('Africa')),
                    Tab(child: Text('Asia')),
                  ]),
                ),
                body: Column(children: [
                  Center(
                      child: ToggleButtons(
                          children: [Text('Day'), Text('Night')],
                          onPressed: (int index) {
                            setState(() {
                              for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < isDayTime.length; buttonIndex++) {
                                if (buttonIndex == index) {
                                  isDayTime[buttonIndex] = true;
                                } else {
                                  isDayTime[buttonIndex] = false;
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          isSelected: isDayTime)),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Center(
                      child: ToggleButtons(
                          children: [Text('Spring'), Text('Summer'), Text('Autumn'), Text('Winter')],
                          onPressed: (int index) {
                            setState(() {
                              for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < listSeason.length; buttonIndex++) {
                                if (buttonIndex == index) {
                                  listSeason[buttonIndex] = !listSeason[buttonIndex];
                                } else {
                                  listSeason[buttonIndex] = false;
                                }
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          isSelected: listSeason)),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(children: [
                      Column(children: [ // How to display the satisfying data
                        for (Temperature temp in _temperature)
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              Text(temp.cityName),
                              Text('${temp.cityTemperature.toString()}° C'),
                            ],
                          )
                      ]),
                      Column(), // How to display the satisfying data
                      Column(), // How to display the satisfying data
                      Column(), // How to display the satisfying data
                    ]),
                  )
                ]))));
  }
}
```

---

### Edit 1:

I want to add 2 things as follows:

**1. Add background image in `TabBarView` for each `_tabs` and each
`isDayTime`**

- For each `continentName`, there will be 2 images for Day or Night.

[image]

- Because it is an image, I think I will put it in `Assets` for users to load faster. Besides, to avoid creating more data on json => I will create the filename of image as: "na_day.png" or "na_true.png" and access it by: `Image.asset('assets/${temp.continentName}_${isDayTime}.png')` or something like that

**2. Display `cityName` on background image based on X Y percent position of image**

[image]

- I use data from JSON: `xAlign` & `yAlign` to determine the position of `cityName` on the image (JSON updated)
- As far as I know, it seems the best way is used `IntrinsicHeight`, `Stack` and `Align` to do like this:

```
class DisplayCountry extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Temperature> countries;

  DisplayCountry({this.countries});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      for (Temperature temp in countries)  // I don't know where to put this
        IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Stack(children: [
            Image.asset('assets/${temp.continentName}_${isDayTime}.png'.asset), // Or something like this
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(temp.xAlign / 100 * 2 - 1, temp.yAlign / 100 * 2 - 1),
              child: Text(temp.cityName),
            ),
          ]),
        )
    ]);
  }
}

extension AssetsExtension on String {
  String get asset => this.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "_").replaceAll("'", "_");
}
```

So please help me update `class DisplayCountry` to be able to combine the 2 things above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
class CityTemperature extends StatefulWidget {
  CityTemperature() : super();
  
  @override
  _CityTemperatureState createState() => _CityTemperatureState();
}

class _CityTemperatureState extends State<CityTemperature> {
  List<Temperature> _temperature = [];
  List<String> _tabs = [];
  Map<String, bool> isDayTime = {'Day': true, 'Night': false};
  Map<String, bool> listSeason = {'Spring': false, 'Summer': false, 'Autumn': false, 'Winter': true};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var response = json.decode(jsonFile);
    _temperature = List<Temperature>.from(response.map((x) => Temperature.fromJson(x)));
    _tabs = _temperature.map<String>((x) => x.continentName).toSet().toList();
    /*
    TemperatureServices.getTemperature().then((temperature) {
      setState(() {
        _temperature = temperature;
      });
    });*/
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
            length: _tabs.length,
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Temperature'),
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: _tabs.map((String name) => Tab(text: name)).toList()
                  ),
                ),
                body: Column(children: [
                  Center(
                      child: ToggleButtons(
                          children: isDayTime.keys.map((key) => Text(key)).toList(),
                          onPressed: (int index) {
                            String indexKey = isDayTime.keys.toList()[index];
                            setState(() {
                              isDayTime.updateAll(
                                (key, value) => key == indexKey ? true : false);
                              }
                            );
                          },
                          isSelected: isDayTime.values.toList())),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Center(
                      child: ToggleButtons(
                          children: listSeason.keys.map((key) => Text(key)).toList(),
                          onPressed: (int index) {
                            String indexKey = listSeason.keys.toList()[index];
                            setState(() {
                              listSeason.updateAll(
                                (key, value) => key == indexKey ? 
                                !listSeason[indexKey] : false);
                            });
                          },
                          isSelected: listSeason.values.toList())),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(
                      children: _tabs.map((String name) {
                        return DisplayCountry(
                          countries: List<Temperature>.from(_temperature)
                          ..retainWhere((temperature) => 
                            temperature.continentName == name 
                            && temperature.isDayTime == isDayTime['Day']
                            && temperature.seasonName == listSeason.keys.firstWhere(
                            (k) => listSeason[k] == true, orElse: () => 'Nothing'))
                        );
                      }).toList()
                    ),
                  )
                ]
             )
         )
    );
  }
}

class DisplayCountry extends StatelessWidget{
  final List<Temperature> countries;
  
  DisplayCountry({this.countries});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return Column(
     children: [
       for(Temperature temp in countries)
           Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Text(temp.cityName),
              Text('${temp.cityTemperature.toString()}° C'),
             ],
           )
     ]
   ); 
  }
}
```

I create a list called _tabs with all the continentName of _temperatures, then added toSet and toList. toSet converts it to a set, a set is an iterable that doesn't allow repeated values, and then I converted it back to list, that way I have a list of unique continentName (NA, EU, etc).

In DefaultTabController I add _tabs.length and in tabView I create a list of _tab.map, which creates a list of widgets of DisplayCountry, I use retainwhere to keep only the ones that satisfies the conditions (same continentName that the one in the tab, same seasonName that the one selected and isDayTime if it's true is day else night)

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

```
class DisplayImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Temperature> countries;
  final String continentName;
  final bool isDayTime;
  
  DisplayImage({this.countries , this.continentName, this.isDayTime});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: [
      Image.asset('assets/$continentName_$isDayTime.png'.asset), 
        fit: BoxFit.cover,),
      for (Temperature temp in countries)
        Positioned(
          left: temp.xAlign * size.width / 100.0,
          top: temp.yAlign  / 2 * size.height / 100.0,
          child: Text('${temp.cityName} ${temp.cityTemperature.toString()}° C'),
        )
    ]);
  }
}
```

and when calling it in the TabView

```
TabBarView(
  children: _tabs.map((String name) {
    return DisplayImage(
       continentName: name,
       isDayTime: isDayTime['Day'],
       countries: List<Temperature>.from(_temperature)
         ..retainWhere((temperature) =>
           temperature.continentName == name &&
           temperature.isDayTime == isDayTime['Day'] &&
           temperature.seasonName ==
           listSeason.keys.firstWhere(
            (k) => listSeason[k] == true,
            orElse: () => 'Nothing')));
  }).toList())
```

As far as I understand you can use the fit property of the stack (StackFit.passthrough) and it will work the same as intrinsicHeight. From the documentation

```
StackFit.passthrough 
For example, if a Stack is an Expanded child of a Row, the horizontal constraints will be tight and the vertical constraints will be loose.
```

In this case you're using an Expanded in a column so it has horizontal loose and vertical tight. Then do some math and try the Align widget if the positioned doesnt work as you want

Comment: Yeahh, I know you will respond to me xD. There are no words to show my appreciation, this is what I expected. Only thing [that](https://i.imgur.com/SDrlZ3i.jpg) how to link `jsonFile` to a specific [link](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tft-test-48c87.appspot.com/o/VAL%20-%20cityTime.json?alt=media&token=a7393697-8573-4d3c-bfd5-4628bdbb0f4a) or from json file in an asset

Comment: Ah, nvm, I I figured out :D

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to change that, I didn't have TemperatureServices to get the list so I just made it out of the Json string

Comment: Please don't mind, you helped me a lot :P BTW , I've edited the post to add more questions, please help me more xD

Comment: those coordinates are based on what? the size of the image?

Comment: Yep, based on full width and full height of image, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488230/flutter-how-to-insert-icon-action-based-on-x-y-percent-position-of-image) describes it more clearly :D

Comment: I didn't test it but try combine the logic of the for with the one of your toher post if the position is off

Comment: Thank you, only thing that regarding load image from Assets, [it](https://i.imgur.com/yRFvl1N.jpg) seems miss something, please check for me: ">

Comment: I updated it, just change it to countries.first.continentName and isDayTime to get the actual value to the asset path

Comment: It shows [error](https://i.imgur.com/GV07cZW.jpg) when `listSeason` is not selected, maybe it needs some more conditions :D

Comment: you're right never considered that, in that case add those parameters in the construtor, so it depends on the value of the day/night button and the tab name being displayed (NA, EU, etc)

Comment: Everything is perfect and beautiful now, I can't believe that this issue I asked 6 days ago then no one answered it fully, and you take only 1 day to solve it all. Thanks for being a big help again xD

Comment: I have a new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777866/flutter-how-to-custom-header-from-json), could you pls help me with `retainWhere` or something like that :D

Comment: For `ToggleButtons` **listSeason**, I tried changing to the case of _"multiple buttons to be simultaneously selected, while requiring none of the buttons to be selected."_ with this code: `listSeason.updateAll((key, value) => key == indexKey = !listSeason[indexKey]);` but it doesn't seem right, please help me correct it :">

Comment: If you want to have multiple buttons selected then it would be easier to just update the button pressed, not all, use update instead of updateAll `listSeason.update(indexKey. !listSeason[indexKey]);`

Comment: It shows error [here](https://i.imgur.com/TQq9rgS.jpg), am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, multiple buttons selected => work! But `TabBarView` does not show all `cityName`. I think because the condition in use is `firstWhere` [link](https://i.imgur.com/713sell.jpg), but I tried replacing it with `where`; `any` ... that didn't work :(. Please help me fix it :D

Comment: Maybe checking if the key of the map is true `listSeason[temperature.seasonName] == true` temperature.seasonName is a String of the same value as the keys of the map so it could help you check if the value of that key is true